# Using two jQuery functions, getting "ReferenceError: document is not defined" on the second one

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing an MVC application and on one page I need to dynamically give an ID to all the  elements because of the way the table is rendered and how data is passed to an from it. The first jQuery function works fine, the second one does not at all though. When I check the console in firebug I get the error

> "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

on that function/I'm sure I'm just not getting something syntactically right, but I can't figure out what could be wrong. My code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable1 = $('#example1').dataTable({
        sScrollX: "100%",
        sScrollY: "200px",
        bFilter: false,
        bScrollCollapse: true,
        bPaginate: false,
        bScrollInfinite: true,
        iScollLoadGap: 10,
        oLanguage: {
            sZeroRecords: "There are no records that match your search criterion",
        }
    }).makeEditable({ sUpdateURL: "/Home/UpdateData" });

});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $(documuent).ready(function () { var editChange = $('td').replaceWith('<td id = "@Html.ValueFor(x => x.name)" >'); });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guarantee that your error is not `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a typo in the second block: `documuent` instead of `document`.

```
$(documuent).ready(function ()
// ----^     remove the extra "u"
```

Comment: @Danger_Fox - If you have another question then please post that as a **new** question.